# Sencha Cmd disable compressor

Tags: sencha-cmd, extjs6

Does anyone know how to remove compression of javascript file in sencha cmd?
I want that my **production** *app.js* file what fully readable.

And I want to configure this in my *app.json* if possible.

I did this:

```
/**
 * Settings specific to production builds.
 */
"production": {
    "compressor": null, // compressor null
    "output": {
        "js": {
            "optimize": false, // optimize false
        },
        "appCache": {
            "enable": false,
            "path": "../cache.appcache"
        }
    },
    "loader": {
        "cache": "${build.timestamp}"
    },
    "cache": {
        "enable": false
    }
}
```

But whereas the compressor option work, at the end my file is still "compressed" (not minified but still in one line).

I try the optimize method in the ideal situation, I would like all Sencha Cmd optimization to be perform *except* to shrink everything in one line...

If somebody know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks to @bnz, the proposed answer was not fully right but it helps me found the solution.

So, to disable the last compression of the `app.js` file during the build process, you have to go to your `<appFolder>/.sencha/app/production.properties` and this directive:

```
enable.resource.compression=false
```

I did not found yet how to set this in the app.json

Answer (score 2):

No answer worked for me, but I found further possible solutions at Sencha Forum (that worked): https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?315722-How-to-ignore-compression-in-production-build

I leave it here for future people reaching this thread :)

[copied from the link]

- Sencha Cmd v6.5.3.16:

app.json:

```
"production": {
    "compressor": {
        "type": "none"
    }
}
```

To disable optimizations:

```
"output": {
    "js": {
        "optimize": false
    }
}
```

- Sencha Cmd 6.2.2.36 (change all the following):

app.json:

```
"production": {
    "compressor": {
        "type": "none"
    }
}
```

.sencha/app/production.properties:

```
enable.resource.compression=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Using app.json you can add

```
"debug" : {
   "enable":false/true
}
```

to your production build object.

If you wanna disable this in general, until the next app upgrade, 
you can have a look under

```
.sencha/app/production.defaults.properties
```

OR better to overwrite the settings

```
.sencha/app/production.properties
```

You need to set

```
build.options.debug=true
```

there.